# c# How write hex value in registry , instead of decimal value?

Tags: c#

How can i write in registry DWORD hexadecimal value ? Instead of decimal value, like in this code example ?

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine;
key = klase.CreateSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows");
key.SetValue("CSDVersion2", "100", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
key.Close();
```

Solution is !

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine;
key = klase.CreateSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows");
key.SetValue("CSDVersion2", Convert.ToInt32("100", 16), RegistryValueKind.DWord);
key.Close();
```

Comment: I solved this problem ! Thanks for advance !

Answer (score 3):

`SetValue` takes an object, so you can give it a plain ol' integer. I would do something like this:

```
key.SetValue("CSDVersion2", 0x100, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

That sets CSDVersion2, to 0x100 hex, or 256 in decimal.

Comment: I believe it's more about how to convert from `int` to `hex`.

Comment: @Tigran I think what the OP is asking is how to give SetValue a hexadecimal literal. It seems a little weird to give `SetValue` a string when you are trying to set a DWORD.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Convert.ToInt32(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx) overload.

```
string strHexValue = Convert.ToInt32("100", 16).ToString();
```

where `16` is base.