# Looking for a recommendation for inserting value to registry

Tags: c#, windows-ce

i try to insert value to registry in C# like this:

```
RegistryKey key;
key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Drivers\\BuiltIn\\Touch");
key.SetValue("InitialState", 0x4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

but nothing happand

when i insert by hand under  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Drivers\\BuiltIn\\Touch`
i insert value `00000004 (Hexidecima)` it works

how to do it right ?

Comment: `Gold` have you tried using a `Golden Search` look at the `Related` links section, come on now people with a rep that High one would think that you would know how to implement a simple google search.. show some more effort please.. [How to Insert Hex Values into Registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11569462/c-sharp-how-write-hex-value-in-registry-instead-of-decimal-value?rq=1) that's one of the Related links on this page..

Comment: Why are you trying to access HKLM via Registry.CurrentUser (HKCU)?

Comment: if you are not sure what the `Registry` can or can not do in regards to `MUCKING UP YOUR MACHINE` I would second that motion, `Stay away from the registry`

Comment: Given your code, you should be looking for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\BuiltIn\Touch` as the location for your created key/value...assuming such a thing is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have a clear error in your statement

You try to use the CurrentUser RegistryKey to write in the LocalMachine registry hive

```
RegistryKey key;
key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("Drivers\\BuiltIn\\Touch");
key.SetValue("InitialState", 0x4, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

Comment: Note the tags, it's win-ce.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the key: key.Close(); If I remember correctly, the register is not updated until you call close(). Here's MSDN: [MSDN Add Registry Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h5e7chcf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)